# If then else and dlookup challenge in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

Its been a long time since I have used coded in VBA, and I am rusty...

Trying to look at a field, which is populated by a combo box, within a table to see if it is null or not.  Based upon the field having value or not, the code determines which form to open.

[table].field

Form1
Form2

here is what I have attempted to no avail

```
If DLookup("[field]", "table", IsNull) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "form1", acNormal
        End If
    If DLookup("[field]", "table", NotIsNull) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "form2", acNormal
```

I can't get this to run without errors.  Help!

Comment: Thanks...  But I am now getting a Compile Error: Argument not optional in the IsNull

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you've got a combo-box on a form, the combo-box gets its values from a table.  If the selected value is blank then open one form, if it's got a value open another form?

Based on a two column Combo-Box (column 0 is hidden key value, column 1 holds the value we're after):

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    With Me.Combo0
        If .Column(1) = "" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acNormal
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3", acNormal
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Based on a 1 column combo:

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    With Me.Combo0
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acNormal
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3", acNormal
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this, but now I am getting a Run-Time error 2501 The Open Form action was canceled....  Below is the real code.

Comment: DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        With Me.Combo5
        If .Column(2) = "" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "01 A03 SchdlcreateCompanySelectError", acNormal
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "01 A02 SchdlcreateMarketerSelect", acNormal
        End If
    End With
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Comment: DoCmd.OpenForm "01 A02 SchdlcreateMarketerSelect", acNormal is highlighted by the bugger

Comment: Sorry, not sure why you're getting that error. With `.Column(2)` you're looking at the third column in the control which will return Null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Good stuff. What was the problem in the end?

Comment: I couldn't tell you.  I re-coded and then it worked...  Most likely I misspelled an object or didn't have all the necessary code...